# How to deploy custom candy machine program

Tags: anchor, metaplex, candy-machine

I was trying to deploy my own modified version of Metaplex's NFT Candy machine on Devnet from "https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/tree/master/candy-machine/program" but i didn't find any tutorial please can provide me the command lines and steps to deploy it.

Comment: Do you have anchor, anchor-cli, rust installed?

Comment: @WrathionTBP, yes of course but what is the command and where i should run them

Answer (score 0):

Before sugar, this is how you would use the CMV2: https://hackmd.io/@hnbl/solanacandymachineguide. You're going to use need the create candy machine method.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to deploy my own candy machine smart contract not Cli to deploy collection with candy machine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `anchor build`, this will provide you a new keypair where its Public key is ur Candy machine instance programID that you have to change on ur `declare_id` in `lib.rs`.

Then you have to set up the anchor.TOML file with the following things:

```
[provider]
cluster = "devnet"                    # The cluster used for all commands (use mainnet to deploy to mainnet).
wallet = "~/.config/solana/id.json"     # The keypair used for all commands (this wallet will deploy the program so you will need SOL here, idk how much you will need atm but make sure to have at least 20SOL).
```

```
[programs.devnet]     #Use programs.mainnet if you wanna deploy to mainnet
my_program = "Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS" #Here goes the public key that you set on lib.rs before.
```

Again, make sure to have sol in ur wallet in order to deploy the program maybe it can cost 20 or more SOL.

Finally in order to deploy you will have to use `anchor deploy` and you will have to wait in order to see if the deploy was succesfull or not. Test first on devnet to avoid any error, and also check some tutorials on [how to deploy a solana program using anchor](https://lorisleiva.com/create-a-solana-dapp-from-scratch/getting-started-with-solana-and-anchor#create-a-new-anchor-project)

Comment: Thanks for your time, There is only a file "cargo.TOML" and i think that i need to use cargo build or is the same as anchor

Comment: You never used `anchor init project-name` to init the anchor project?

Comment: Unfortunately no, i'm still beginner on anchor projects.

Comment: Please follow the guide that I left on the answer, it will show you the steps, basically you already have the code, just need an anchor project setted up and the guide will help you

Comment: Yeah, That's right and thank you so much.